# Route traffic between subnets without nat using linux as router

Tags: linux, networking, router

I have a bit of network experience but somehow i can't seem to connect to subnets using a linux box

my current network looks like this

```
#########
# LAN 1 # (192.178.178.0/24)
#########
    |
######### (192.168.178.1/24) eth0
# LINUX #
######### (192.168.177.1/24) wlan0
    |
#########
# LAN 2 # (192.168.177.0/24)
#########
```

The linux box runs DHCP on both interfaces
The linux box distributes the following routes via DHCP

```
[192.168.178.0/24 via 192.168.177.1] on wlan0
[192.168.177.0/24 via 192.168.178.1] on eth0
```

and i have set net.ipv4.ip_forward=1
on the linux box

but devices on different LAN can't ping each other, even though they have the route applied

i know i could solve this with MASQUERADE nat
but i want to know the source ip of packages on the recieving end

output from route get is as follows

```
user@router:~ $ ip route get to 192.168.177.2 from 192.168.178.3 iif eth0
192.168.177.2 from 192.168.178.3 dev wlan0
    cache iif wlan0

user@router:~ $ ip route get to 192.168.178.3 from 192.168.177.2 iif wlan0
192.168.178.3 from 192.168.177.2 dev eth0
    cache iif eth0
```

Comment: Does the router _receive_ the ping attempts? Does it forward them through to the other interface? Does it receive responses?

Comment: @user1686 when in lan 1 i can ping the lan2 address of the router, so it at least recieves the request, but how would i check the other things

Comment: Use a packet capture tool – [tcpdump](https://packetlife.net/media/library/12/tcpdump.pdf)/tshark/termshark/[wireshark](https://www.wireshark.org/#download) are common. In particular, both `tcpdump -n -e -i eth0` and `tcpdump -n -e -i wlan0` are a good start (optionally filtered for `"not port 22"` if you're doing this over SSH). When a device in LAN A tries to ping something on LAN B (not the router itself), you should be seeing that ping (ICMP Echo) packet arrive at one of the router's interfaces and leave through another (possibly after some ARP querying).

Comment: @user1686
yes an ICMP echo request arrives at eth0 and leaves wlan0, with the correct source (device LAN 1, and destination device LAN 2) and ARP gets resolved but gets no response

Comment: Can you similarly check whether the packet shows up on the destination device's network interface? And you also see the same in the other direction (pinging LAN1 from LAN2), then it sounds like network routing is working as it should – it's delivering packets in both directions; it's the end devices that choose to not reply.

Comment: @user1686 yeah i figured, it's the windows firewalls on the end devices (that im forced to use) that chooses not to reply, i can establish connections between the devices

Answer (score 0):

The culprit was microsoft windows, the routing works fine
but windows does not respond to ping request if they're not from the same network domain etc...

Comment: Then reconfigure the firewall – `wf.msc` has built-in rules that only need to be enabled.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

If you're seeing packets leave the correct interface at the router (and if they have the right "destination MAC" too), then routing is being performed correctly. Even if there are no responses, it's enough that you see the request packets being forwarded in both directions.

(Where packets actually go is easy to see with a packet capture tool – Wireshark runs on Windows as well, so you can use it to verify that the OS is *at least* seeing the ICMP Echo packets arrive.)

By default, Windows systems do not respond to ping requests at all, unless File Sharing is enabled in which case (IIRC) it's limited to the current subnet.

Use the **`wf.msc`** tool to activate the built-in "File and Printer Sharing (ICMP-In)" rules to allow the packets to go through.